# How can I take numbers in hex format and do arithmatic and output in hex format in bash shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

In bash, I wish I could output sum of two input values, all the input and output string represented in hex format as follows.
This is what I want to do.

```
$ script1 0x80200000 0x800
sum = 0x80200800
$
```

How should I write the script 'script1' for this? Of course this doesn't work.

```
sum = $1 + $2
echo "sum = " $sum
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic), which supports `0x` hex values but outputs in base 10, and print in hex using `printf`:

```
$ printf "%#X\n" $(( 0x80200000 + 0x800 ))
0X80200800
$ printf "%#x\n" $(( 0x80200000 + 0x800 ))
0x80200800
```